# Finding documents containing at least one embedded object missing a given field

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there an efficient way to find all documents of a Mongo collection that have at least one embedded object missing a given field?

I'm trying:

```
Response.where('answers.question_id' => nil)
```

However, this only returns Responses for which every answer is missing a question_id, rather than responses that contain at least one answer missing a question_id.

I could loop through the Responses testing each, but this is horrendously slow for the size of the database I'm working with, so I'm keen to find a way to construct a query to narrow the response list.

EDIT:

```
Response.where(:'answers.question_id'.exists => false)
```

Still does not solve my problem - it still only finds responses for which *all* embedded answers are missing question_id, not responses for which *any* embedded answers are missing question_id.

Comment: there's a [FAQ entry](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-query-for-fields-that-have-null-values).

Comment: @jimoleary - thanks, but that's for finding documents with a null field, not documents containing at least one embedded object with a null field

Comment: sorry my initial response was a tad terse! look at the description of the $exists operator at the end of the FAQ entry. It describes how to find missing fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried either of the following?

```
Response.where(:answers => { "$elemMatch" => { :"answer_id".exists => false }})
Response.where(:answers.elem_match => { :answer_id.exists => false})
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Response.where(:answers.elem_match => { :question_id => nil})
does exactly what I was after.